# UIView Delete Itself?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a `UIView` subclass called `ToolbarView` that sort of acts like a floating window and has a `UIToolbar` that has an "X" button that can make the window disappear. My question is, is it possible for the object to delete itself from within its own class?

For instance, within `ToolbarView.m`, I have a method `closeButtonPushed` which fires when the X button is pushed. Is it as simple as to remove the view from its `superview`, and then call `dealloc`? Is it even necessary to call `dealloc` as once it is removed from the `superview` there won't be any other pointers to it. Or is this bad memory practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, don't call dealloc ever.  If the superview is the only object that has a reference to your view, removing the view will cause its retain count to go to 0, and the runtime will then deallocate the object for you.

Comment: Don't you have to nil it though, after the removeFromSuperView?

Comment: Probably a best practice to ensure you don't access bad memory after the object is deleted, but not necessary.  It will not affect the memory management at all

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is in `closeButtonPushed` method is, call

```
 [self removeFromSuperView];
```

it will remove the `ToolbarView` object and IOS will call the `dealloc` method and release objects. No need to call `dealloc` manually.

Comment: dealloc will not necessarily be called after calling [self removeFromSuperView]. you may need to set the object pointer to nil in the parent class.